# Bash script to scan sub-directories and copy contents of file to another file

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

I need to do a bash command that will look through every home directory on a system, and copy the contents of the .forward file to a single file, along with copying the name of the directory it just copied from.  So for example the final file would be something like forwards.txt and listeings would be

```
/home/user1
user1@email.com
/home/user2
user2@email.com
```

I've used this to list them to screen.

```
find /home -name '*' | cat /home/*/.forward
```

and it will print out the forward in each file but I'm not getting it to prefix it with which home directory it came from. Would I need to use a loop to do this?  I had this test loop,

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in /home/*
        do
                if [ -d $i ]
                        then
                                pwd >> /tmp/forwards.txt
                                cat /home/*/.forward >> /tmp/forwards.txt
                fi
        done
```

But it went through the four home directories on my test setup and the forwards.txt file had the following listed four times.

```
/tmp
user1@email.com
user2@email.com
user3@email.com
user3@email.com
```

Thanks.

Comment: This feels like a combination of `find` and `-exec` could make this a one-liner (heads to his Bash shell prompt...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is corrected version of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in /home/*
        do
                if [ -f "$i/.forward" ]
                then
                                echo "$i" >> /tmp/forwards.txt
                                cat "$i/.forward" >> /tmp/forwards.txt
                fi
        done
```

Some points:

- we checks for presents of `.forward` file inside home directory instead of existence of home directory itself
- on each iteration `$i` contains name of home directory (like `/home/user1`). So we use its value instead of output of `pwd` command which always returns current directory (it doesn't change in our case)
- instead of `/home/*/.forward` we use `"/home/$i/.forward"` because `*` after substitution gives to us all directories, while we need only current

---

Another, shortest version of this script may looks like this:

```
find /home -type f -name '.forward' | while read F; do
    dirname "$F" >>/tmp/forwards.txt
    cat "$F" >>/tmp/forwards.txt
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I quickly realized after I typed that that echo not pwd was what I wanted to do. One thing, I had to change /home/$i/.forwards to $i/.forward

Answer (score 1):

I would write

```sh
for fwd in /home/*/.forward; do
    dirname "$fwd"
    cat "$fwd"
done > forwards.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

A one liner (corrected):

```
find /home -maxdepth 2 -name ".forward" -exec echo "{}" >> /tmp/forwards.txt \; -exec cat "{}" >> /tmp/forwards.txt \;
```

This will output:

```
/home/user1/.forward
a@a.a
b@b.b
/home/user2/.forward
a@b.c
```

Comment: The only thing that isn't doing is the echo of the current directory.